# Calling a Module Method for a Specific Class

Tags: ruby, class, module

If I have two classes that both include the same module but want a module method to be called only when one of the classes is saved how would I do this?

```
    module MusicMaker
      def good_music
        puts "this music rocks"
      end
    end

    class Jazz
      include MusicMaker
    end

    class ClassicRock
      include MusicMaker
    end
```

So I want both classes to include the `MusicMaker` module but want the `good_music` method to be called only when `ClassicRock` is saved and not when `Jazz` is saved. I want to do this inside the `MusicMaker` module and not in the classes.

Comment: What do you mean by _when <a Class> is saved_ ?

Comment: i mean when a model is saved into the database

Comment: Then it is important to inherit those classes from `ActiveRecord::Base` or `ApplicationRecord`. Otherwise everybody will think you're talking about plain Ruby classes.

Answer (score 0):

Say your module defines a `save` method, and you want it to behave differently based on which class it gets called on. You can put a conditional in there and check the value of `self.class`:

```
module MusicMaker
  def save
    case self.class
    when Jazz
      puts "jazz saved"
    when ClassicRock
      puts "classic rock saved"
    end
  end
end

Jazz.new.save # => "jazz saved"
ClassicRock.new.save # => "classic rock saved"
```

This kind of begs the question of why you would use a module at all in this situation rather than define a different `save` method for each of the classes like so:

```
class Jazz
  def save
    puts "jazz saved"
  end
end

class ClassicRock
  def save
    puts "classic rock saved"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using activerecord, I believe you can use the `before_save` method in the `ClassicRock` class. Just like

```
class ClassicRock < ApplicationRecord
  include MusicMaker
  before_save :good_music
end
```

Comment: is it possible to do this without changing the code of any of the ActiveRecord models?

Comment: what do you mean by changing the code? without the `before_save` method?